# Rails and JS. All the fields are combined and sent to the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a novice programmer. 
In the form of added javascript functions to add and remove fields. 
All the fields are combined and sent to the database?
Help please.

**new.html.slim**

```
= simple_form_for @flight do |f|
  p
    = f.text_field :flight_date, class: 'datepicker'
  p
    #GroupAirports
    input#addButton type="button" value=("Add of Airport")
    input#removeButton type="button" value=("Remove of Airport")
    input#combineButton type="button" value=("Combine of Airport")
  p
    = f.button :submit, data: { disable_with: 'Saving...' }, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addButton").click(function () {

  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'AirportDiv' + counter);

  newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Airport #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                             '<input type="text" name="airport' + counter +
                             '" id="airport' + counter + '" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#GroupAirports");
  counter++;
     });

  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
      alert("No more airport to remove");
      return false;
    }
  counter--;
    $("#AirportDiv" + counter).remove();
  });

  $("#combineButton").click(function () {
  var msg = '';
  for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
    msg += $('#airport' + i).val() + "-";
  }
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

Insert button "Combine of Airport" to make sure that the fields are not empty.
I want to combine all the fields created via javascript, split by comma and save in one field of the database.

Comment: It is not very clear what's the issue. However it seems you might wanna use cocoon gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: I want to combine all the fields created via javascript, split by comma and save in one field of the database.

Comment: BrioSatse, no. It's not nested form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Airport #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                         '<input type="text" name="airport' + counter +
                         '" id="airport' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

I would go with:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Airport #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                         '<input type="text" name="airports[]" id="airport' + 
                         counter + '" value="" >');
```

This will send all the inputs values in a nice array. You can then get it in your controller with:

```
airports = params.delete(:airports).join(',')
```

And assign it to the field.

Comment: Thank you, BrioSatse! Respect!